# How to link a button inside of a linked article?

Tags: button, hyperlink, anchor, article

I know that you can't put a link inside a link, but how would link a button inside of an already linked ? I'm trying to recreate the aside on the pcfinancial website.

Here is what I did which I know is incorrect:

```
<a href="https://www.pcfinancial.ca/en/learning-hub/blog/introducing-the-new-pc-money-account/" target="_blank" title="Link to Article">
                        <article>
                            <img src="images/first-article.png" alt="Introducing the new PC Money Account">
                            <p><a href="https://www.pcfinancial.ca/en/learning-hub/blog/category/fuel-financial-fluency/" target="_blank" title="Fuel Financial Fluency">Financial Fluency</a></p>
                            <h3>Introducing the new PC Money&trade; Account</h3>
                            <p><a href="https://www.pcfinancial.ca/en/learning-hub/blog/author/pc-financial-team/" target="_blank" title="Link to Author">By PC Financial Team</a></p>
                            <p>Read Article</p>
                        </article>
                       </a>
```

Now how does one get the button for "Financial Fluency" that is linked in the article like it is on this website: https://www.pcfinancial.ca/en/

I'm in a coding course and had to recreate this in HTML. We have not begun CSS yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove link on a top of `<article>` link and put its on your `<img>` `<h3>` and `<p>` tags like this:

```
<article>
    <a href="https://www.pcfinancial.ca/en/learning-hub/blog/introducing-the-new-pc-money-account/" target="_blank" title="Link to Article">
        <img src="images/first-article.png" alt="Introducing the new PC Money Account">
        <p><a href="https://www.pcfinancial.ca/en/learning-hub/blog/category/fuel-financial-fluency/" target="_blank" title="Fuel Financial Fluency">Financial Fluency</a></p>
        <h3>Introducing the new PC Money&trade; Account</h3>
        <p><a href="https://www.pcfinancial.ca/en/learning-hub/blog/author/pc-financial-team/" target="_blank" title="Link to Author">By PC Financial Team</a></p>
    </a>
    <a href="YOUR_LINK_HERE">
        <p>Read Article</p> <!-- and use <button> element if you think it is a button-->
    </a>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve the problem really since the article itself needs to be linked. The whole thing is clickable to the article which is why I linked it as such. but the <a> for the financial fluency is what is giving me errors in the validator as an <a> cannot be nested in another <a> which is the entirety of the article. Can I link things through CSS via <button> ?